# Error connecting to Debian 9 VPS via RDP

Tags: debian, gnome, x-server, vps, rdp

I am using A DEBIAN 9 VPS with 1GB RAM and 20GB storage. Soon after I installed it on cloud, I connected to it via PUTTY and there was absolutely no problem. I then upgraded and updated my machine (as root) and also installed xserver-xorg,xrdp and GNOME .  I started them (for Gnome I went to init.d and used "sh gdm3 start" and started some more services in that same folder) and tried to connect using remote desktop. I see this screen (xorg login screen):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsBfE.jpg]

When I put the user name and password, The authentication is successful and it starts loading the Gnome login screen. I see the gray background of login screen for 0.5 seconds and the entire Remote desktop Window closes.

I can access the machine directly through my VPS cloud website in chrome itself (but that's too slow and doesn't work properly). When I saw the desktop settings it showed that screen sharing was off. I couldn't even turn it on.

Also , one time when I tried connecting via RDP for like the 15th time, I tried doing it in full screen and it showed an error message that said :"network closed"

For your reference, This is the image of the LAST screen I see before the rdp window closes:

[image: last screen]

VPS details

- Hosting provider: [aruba.it](https://aruba.it/)
- OS: Debian 9 64-bit
- Memory: 1 GB
- Processor: 1 vCPU
- Storage: 20 GB

Comment: What rdp client software are you using?  Does it show any messages (eg. in its log files) when the window suddenly closes?

Comment: To build off of user JigglyNaga, please update your post with your network configuration. Does the VPS allow the RDP port to be opened?